# Android: is it possible to jump to certain section in text view?

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview in a scrollview where there is several text paragraphs ..

What i want to do is: based on a button clicked by the user, to jump the focus of textview to a certain text paragraph ..

Is it possible to jump to certain section in text view in Android? if yes, can you put any links explaining this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `textView.scrollBy(int x, int y)` or `textView.scrollTo(int x, int y)`.